# Can't import mssql to Angular 2 project

Tags: sql-server, node.js, angular, npm

I installed `mssql` and `@types/mssql` via `npm` and changed my `systemjs.config` to:

```
System.config({
    paths: {
        // alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/',
    },
    map: {
        app: 'app',
        ...
        'mssql': 'npm:mssql'
    },
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        ...
        mssql: {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```

When I add a import statement like

```
import * as mssql from "mssql"
```

I get the following errors:

```
"http://localhost:3000/util" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
"http://localhost:3000/promise" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
"http://localhost:3000/fs" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
"http://localhost:3000/events" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
"http://localhost:3000/url" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
"http://localhost:3000/querystring" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd expect `mssql` to be server-only.